# How to make htacces pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to implement a pattern in htacces to change the url to a specific pattern.
My main file is dashboard.php. One GET variable is constant and another are optional.
Here is an example illustrating my idea:

```
dashboard.php?view=foo&var1=bar&var2=something
```

Redirects to

```
dashboard/foo?var1=bar&var2=something
```

I'm not good at writing conditions to .htacces.
Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Optiona -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(dashboard)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)